# Styling sidebar with main content + sticky header/footer using flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a sidebar and main content as well as a navbar built with [SUIR](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) . I want to make sure that the main content is always in view and not cut off when the sidebar is visible.

Here's my dashboard component that's rendering the sidebar/content components

```
const Dashboard = props => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ height: "100vh", display: "flex", flexFlow: "column nowrap" }}
    >
      <div>
        <PageHeader />
      </div>
      <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <SidebarExample>
          <DashboardContent />
        </SidebarExample>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I also have a [codesandbox here with the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-content-styling-023q1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there's an element in between your flex row element and the two inner elements (sidebar and content). Here's what I see in the browser:

```
<div style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
  <div class="ui segment pushable"> <!-- this element needs flex -->
    <div class="ui inverted vertical ..."> ... </div>
    <div class="pusher"> ... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Restructure a bit to fix that and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you can solve this problem by just showing your menu over your main content using `position:absolute;` and `z-index`.

But from what I think you want, you could try a CSS approach like this:

```
-----------------------------
|    |                      |
|    |                      |
|    |                      |
|    |                      |
|    |                      |
 menu      content
 10%        90%
```

then apply it like this:

```
.menu[style*="hidden"] .content {
   width: 90vw;
}

.menu:not([style*="hidden"]) .content {
   width: 100vw;
}
```

*Assuming you're applying `visibility: hidden;` to your menu when you're hiding it.* Otherwise, you can change "hidden" to whichever property you're applying.

Comment: I've tried applying your suggestions, but couldn't quite get the right layout. I've updated the sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-content-styling-023q1

Comment: How are you hiding the menu currently? what css is being applied?

Comment: So I'm not actually hiding the sidebar anymore, showing a minimal sidebar when it's collapsed. Currently applying this to the pusher sub-component   `style={
          visible
            ? { width: "85%", transition: "250ms ease" }
            : { width: "100%", transition: "250ms ease" }
        }`